# $rk(A)=n$ implies $rk(AB)=rk(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $A \in Mat_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $B \in Mat_{n\times p}(\mathbb{R})$.
>
> Assume $rk(A)=n$. Prove that $rk(AB)=rk(B)$.

Lets start by proving $rk(B) \ge rk(AB)$. Indeed, since the rows of $AB$ are linear combination of $B$'s rows, $AB \subseteq B$ and therefore, $rk(B) \ge rk(AB)$.

Now, I wish to show the other part which is: $rk(AB) \ge rk(B)$. How should I do that? Or maybe I should prove it with another approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}[0]{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\rk}[0]{\mathrm{rk}}$Perhaps you could think of the underlying linear maps 
$$
\beta : \R^{p} \to \R^{n}, \qquad \beta(x) = B x,
$$
and
$$
\alpha : \R^{n} \to \R^{m}, \qquad \alpha(y) = A y.
$$
Then $\rk(A) = n = \dim(\R^{n})$ means that $\alpha$ is injective. And $\rk(B)$ is the dimension of the image of $\beta$, which is a subspace of $\R^{n}$.

Comment: So I should observe, $(\alpha \circ \beta)(v)$ and then what? Sorry, but I don't really understand how to proceed..

Comment: @AnnieOK, since $\alpha$ is injective, it preserves dimensions, so the dimension of the image of $\beta$ is the same as the dimension of the image of $\alpha \circ \beta$. Now these two dimensions are exactly the two ranks to be proved equal.

Comment: Can you expand about this sentence please: "since $\alpha$ is injective, it preserves dimensions"?

Comment: Speaking just a little more generally, let $f : V \to W$ be an injective linear map, with $V, W$ vector spaces. Let $v_{1}, \dots, v_{k} \in V$ be linearly independent. I claim $f(v_{1}), \dots, f(v_{k})$ are also l.i. For if $0 = a_{1} f(v_{1}) + \dots + a_{k} f(v_{k})$, then $0 = f(a_{1} v_{1} + \dots + a_{k} v_{k})$, which implies $o = a_{1} v_{1} + \dots + a_{k} v_{k}$, as $f$ is injective, which implies all $a_{i}$ are zero, as $v_{1}, \dots, v_{k}$ are l.i.